# How to reverse the order of my $index in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table like in the picture,when the stop button is clicked the record gets stored in the first row not in the last row because `I ORDER BY EndTime DESC in SQL`,but now I want the Record column to be in reversed.How can I do that?
[image: Downtime Recorder]

HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="previousdowntime in Model.PreviousDowntimeEvents | orderBy:'$index':true">
               <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
               <td>{{Model.GetDowntimeText(previousdowntime.CategoryId)}}</td>
               <td><span ng-bind="previousdowntime.StartTime|date:'shortTime'"></span></td>
               <td><span ng-bind="previousdowntime.EndTime|date:'shortTime'"></span></td>                 
               <td>{{previousdowntime.Comment}}</td>
               <td>{{previousdowntime.TotalMinutes}}  minutes</td> 
             </tr>
```

Comment: You down vote me but you don't tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ variables in the ng-repeat are tools you should use, not change.

If you only want to reverse the values in the Records column use simple maths: {{Model.PreviousDowntimeEvents.length - $index}}

```
<tr ng-repeat="previousdowntime in Model.PreviousDowntimeEvents | orderBy:'$index':true">
     <td>{{Model.PreviousDowntimeEvents.length - $index}}</td>
     <td>{{Model.GetDowntimeText(previousdowntime.CategoryId)}}</td>
     <td><span ng-bind="previousdowntime.StartTime|date:'shortTime'"></span></td>
     <td><span ng-bind="previousdowntime.EndTime|date:'shortTime'"></span></td>                 
    <td>{{previousdowntime.Comment}}</td>
    <td>{{previousdowntime.TotalMinutes}}  minutes</td> 
</tr>
```